When playing using the AudioPlayers package in Flutter, music playing externally stop
When a sound effect plays in my Flutter app, external music (e.g. YouTube Music) stops.
I am using AudioPlayers: 5.2.0
this is part of my code.
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';


class SoundPlayer{

  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  playAudiobySource(String filePath) async {
    await audioPlayer.play(AssetSource(filePath));
  }

  StopAudio() async {
    await audioPlayer.stop();
  }
}

What I want is, I want to hear sound effects in my app while listening to YouTube Music.

This is not a bug, its possibly expected functionality. Refer to their github repo : https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/feature_parity_table.md
